# Classes Python and developing Stack

Tags: python

I have created my own LIFO container class Stack that supports the methods of push, len, pop, and a check on isEmpty.  All methods appear to be working in my example calls, except for when I call a created instance of this class(in my example s) I receive a memory location for the created object when I want to see the actual contents of that object.

```
class Stack:

   x = []

    def __init__(self, x=None):
        if x == None:
            self.x = []
        else:
            self.x = x

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self.x) == 0
    def push(self,p):
        self.x.append(p)
    def pop(self):
        return self.x.pop()
    def __len__(self):
        return(len(self.x))


    s = Stack()    
    s.push('plate 1')
    s.push('plate 2')
    s.push('plate 3')
    print(s)
    print(s.isEmpty())
    print(len(s))
    print(s.pop())
    print(s.pop())
    print(s.pop())
    print(s.isEmpty())
```

I get the result of running this  line `print(s)` to be `<__main__.Stack object at 0x00000000032CD748>t` when I would expect and am looking for `['plate 1','plate 2','plate3']`

Comment: Please fix your ident

Comment: what's wrong about [deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)?

Comment: @deathApril -- Since OP is really just wrapping a list, I assume that this is mostly a learning exercise...

Comment: Yes, if this wasn't a learning exercise, `list` would be fine on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also override `__str__` or `__repr__` if you want your class to have a different representation when printing.  Something like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.x)
```

should do the trick.  `__str__` is what is called by the `str` function (and implicitly called by `print`).  The default `__str__` simply returns the result of `__repr__` which defaults to that funny string with the type and the memory address.

Comment: Yep a learning exercise, new to programming and realized something somewhere was defaulting to the memory address, but couldnt figure out how to correctly overide it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the default implementation of [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__). Otherwise it will use the default implementation which returns an informal string representation of the class, in this case the type and memory address.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.x)
```

Comment: Why would you use `self.__dict__['x']` when you can just use `self.x`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes override `__str__` and/or `__repr__`
Remember `__repr__` can can evaled and return the same object if possible

Comment: `__repr__` can be evaled and return the same object -- That's not exactly true.  *If possible/practical*, it should follow that guideline.  But for most real-world objects, this isn't even practical.